# Python - do same code every other line?

Tags: python, loops

Let's say I have the following code:

```
print("something different1")
time.sleep(1)
print("something different2")
time.sleep(1)
print("something different3")
time.sleep(1)
print("something different4")
time.sleep(1)
```

How can I rewrite it so that I don't have to type time.sleep(1) every other line? just want to save time here. i looked loop functions up on google but im not entirely sure how to do it.

thanks !

edit: thanks for comments so far.

what if i want to do something like this?

```
after1 = discord.get("https://discordapp.com/api/channels/"+(discordchannelid1)+"/messages?limit=2").json()
time.sleep(1)
```

can i keep making the variable after(counter) and (discordchannelid(counter)) increase by 1?

Comment: I'm assuming your actual lines of code are more complicated than just printing different things?

Comment: go for a simple for loop, i think thats what you want

Comment: Why do you want your program to sleep so often? I think you have different problem to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a while loop depending on how many times you want to print this message, along with a for loop. You can break out of the loop when you’ve printed the message as many times as you want in order to avoid an infinite loop. Here is an example.

```
message_number = 0
while message <= 4:
       print(“Do something” + str(message_number))
       message_number += 1
       time.sleep(1)
```

This will continue to print your message so long as the message count is <= 4. The loop will automatically break once we have entered four messages (I chose for because you printed “Do something” 4 times). Each time through the loop it will increment message by += 1 until we print the message four times. We can add time.sleep(1) as the last line of code so that the loop will wait 1 second before executing the code again. We also combine the string with the message count each time we iterate through the while loop.

Comment: what if i want to do something like this? after1 = discord.get("https://discordapp.com/api/channels/"+(discordchannelid1)+"/messages?limit=2").json()
   time.sleep(1)

can i keep making the variable after(counter) and (discordchannelid(counter)) increase by 1?

Answer (score 0):

```
counter = 0
for i in range(60):
    print("something different" + str(counter))
    time.sleep(1)
    counter += 1
```

This is called a "for loop".

"for i in range()" will repeat an action a number of times equal to the input integer.  You can use any variable name you want for "i" and even refer to it in the code as a reference to the specific index (for example, you can refer to a list element with "list[i]").  The integer can come from a variable, such as "for i in range(x)..."

If you're specifically looking to make each line different, you can specify the rules that do that inside your for loop.  In the code I provided above, I incremented a counter by 1 to match your question statement.

Comment: what if i want to do something like this? after1 = discord.get("https://discordapp.com/api/channels/"+(discordchannelid1)+"/messages?limit=2").json()
   time.sleep(1)

can i keep making the variable after(counter) and (discordchannelid(counter)) increase by 1?

Comment: If you're trying to create a new variable each time, then this is a variable variables problem.  You can make each variable a class object, then simply create each instance of the class object inside of a for loop.  So, if you want 4 different variables, then you can say "for i in range(4): new_class = class_type() "